# Determine string literal escape characters in Ado.net

Tags: .net, sql, database, ado.net

Given any DbConnection from any Data Provider, is it possible to determine the character or characters used to quote a string literal as well as escape any special characters within the string? I'm also interested in the characters necessary for quoting schema/table/column name identifiers.

Using parameters to specify these things is not an option as the intent of my application is to help users build a SQL query and having constants within the query is a common scenario.

I can use the DataSourceInformation schema collection to get something like StringLiteralPattern and QuotedIdentifierPattern 
(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254501.aspx) but that only helps me match existing strings and not create them myself.

Comment: I've started to wonder if standard procedure is just to guess. " for identifiers and ' for string literals with \ to escape special chars within the string seems to be the most common (and possibly only) case I've seen. I just worry about comming across some unknown driver that is different.

Answer (score 1):

After creating the connection (called cnn), I did the following for quoting schema/table/column name identifiers:

```
'Get table and column delimiters
Dim sTest As String = ""
Dim sLeftDelimiter As String = ""
Dim sRightDelimiter As String = ""
Dim cmd As DbCommand = cnn.CreateCommand()
Dim adapter As DbDataAdapter = factoryDB.CreateDataAdapter()
Dim builder As DbCommandBuilder = factoryDB.CreateCommandBuilder()
cmd.Connection = cnn
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
builder.DataAdapter = adapter
sTest = builder.QuoteIdentifier("test")
sLeftDelimiter = sTest.Substring(0, 1)
sRightDelimiter = sTest.Substring(5, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a switch statement depending upon provider type and version (as determined from DbConnection) in order to know what delimiters/escape characters to use.